# Python Flask Request.Form not working in IIS

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, request

I have deployed a Python in IIS, Application working fine in my local machine.

I am able to retrieve project_id value from below request.form in local machine code but in IIS its not working.
request.form['projectdetails[project_id]'] I am passing values through Ajax (json).
When code execute above code in IIS I'm facing exception:- 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. Again, same code is working in my local machine.
I have implemented token based authentication.

I tried to log str(request.**dir**()) & str(request.**dict**) and compare with my local machine log but its similar and it doesn't display form values in logs for both.

request_form_dict = request.form
for key in request_form_dict:
logging_config.LogException("create project key logs",str(request_form_dict[key]))
above line also throws exception
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: the bad request is to do with the server and not the code.  `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400` especially given that you can get it working locally....